# Round Off in PHP

Tags: php, rounding

I want to round off the number with exact value of decimal in PHP.

> Eg:
>
> 1.399 => 1.39 or 363.3 => 363.30

I have used `printf("%.2f", 1.399)` and `number_format((float)$a,2,'.','')` but the answer is `1.40` which is incorrect for me.

Comment: do you need 1.39 after rounding off 1.399?

Comment: what would be the correct answer?

Comment: correct answer would be 1.39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `floor()` to round down:

```
$number = 1.399;
$roundedNumber = number_format(floor($number * 100)/100, 2);
echo $roundedNumber; //Returns 1.39
```

Comment: If I generate two numbers with this function its not adding

Comment: $number = 565656.3999;
$roundedNumber = number_format(floor($number * 100)/100, 2);

$number1 = 333656.3999;
$roundedNumber1 = number_format(floor($number1 * 100)/100, 2);

echo $sum = $roundedNumber + $roundedNumber1;

Comment: @PrashantSharma That is because of `number_format` seperators. Change `number_format` to: `number_format(floor($number1 * 100)/100, 2, ".", "");`

Answer (score -1):

Try PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN along with php round() and number_format to include the trailing zero like this
    echo number_format(round( 1.399, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN),2);

Comment: What happens when you fill in `363.30` as a number?

Comment: if we add number_format, then it won't affect the trailing zero. Is there any error in this to put negative feedback now?

Comment: Yes it outputs `1.40` the OP wants to have `1.39`